# Azure Python SDK not able to consume output of list_of_vms with azure-mgmt-compute==20.0.0

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-cloud-services, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-python

I am using azure python sdk for resource management.
below snippet was working with Azure -> azure-mgmt-compute==12.0.0 after upgrade to azure-mgmt-compute==20.0.0 below snippet is not working

```
creds = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id=client_id, secret=secret, tenant=tenant_id, **kwargs)

compute_client =  ComputeManagementClient(creds,
                                   subscription_id,
                                   base_url='https://management.azure.com')

paged_iter = compute_client.virtual_machines.list_all(raw=True)

output = []
paged_iter.get(paged_iter.next_link)
while True:
    chunk = json.loads(paged_iter.raw.response.content)
    if 'nextLink' in chunk:
        paged_iter.get(chunk['nextLink'])
    else:
        break
resp = {'value': output}
print(resp)
```

after upgrade getting error
`AttributeError: 'ItemPaged' object has no attribute 'get'`

Please help to understand how to consume output of  `compute_client.virtual_machines.list_all(raw=True)`

Comment: Why did you wanted to page manually while you get a page iterator that does all for that you? Why doing to raw=True in the first place? If there is a good reason why the iterator was not doing what you wanted it to do, please ask a question in https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues

Comment: How's going? Has your issue got resolved?

Comment: Thanks, @StanleyGong. 
Yes, issue got resolved able to iterate over VMs.
For raw json should I use ```__dict__``` ?

Comment: @LaurentMazuel I have to filter the result based on location or some other params, do you have any suggestion for filtering ?
Also, ``` raw=True``` was used for getting raw json which was generically getting used at my end,  you can put your thoughts for any other best practices or suggestions .
-Thanks

Comment: @SanvarInamdar May I know which way you want to filter VMS? By name，resource group or something others?

Comment: @StanleyGong I want to filter based on location, by name & resource group also will help.

Comment: @SanvarInamdar try `computer_client.virtual_machines.get('<resource group name>','<vm name>')` to get a vm by resource name and vm name and try `computer_client.virtual_machines.list('<resource group name>')` get vms in a resource group

Comment: @StanleyGong how can we get output of ```computer_client.virtual_machines.list_all()``` in json, I need complete model mapping currently after converting to dict using ```computer_client.virtual_machines.list_all().__dict__```  some of the params are still in object format like ``` hardware_profile': <azure.mgmt.compute.v2020_12_01.models._models_py3.HardwareProfile object at 0x00000021F61AE5CD0>```  instead of this I want value of hardware profile.
How can I do complete model mapping ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential

credentials = ClientSecretCredential(
   client_id='',
   client_secret='',
   tenant_id=''
)

subID= ''

computer_client = ComputeManagementClient(credentials,subID)
vms = computer_client.virtual_machines.list_all()

for vm in vms:
   print( vm.name )
```

Result:

[image]
[image]